# How to prevent multiple builds of a library in a workspace, when binaries enable different features?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Cargo workspace with a library and multiple binaries. The binaries enable different features in the library, and I would like to build the library only once (because it's big and building it takes a lot of time).

However, if I invoke `cargo run`/`cargo test`/`clippy` in the directory of one of the packages, the library is rebuilt with only the features enabled by the package I'm building.

Is it possible to tell cargo to apply feature unification as if the whole workspace is being built, when building only one package?

Comment: You can call `cargo run -p foo` from the workspace to build just package `foo`. I don't know what features get taken in that case…

Comment: `cargo run -p foo` enables the features required by package `foo`. `cargo run --bin foo` instead builds with feature unification and then runs `foo`. I would like to have a command that works like the latter when invoked in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant Cargo issue is https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4463

Currently, the solution involves using cargo-hakari